# Verifying Sessions

Tags: okta, okta-api

We currently support mobile and desktop apps. Our product is somewhat unique. We have our own secure authentication method. However, I've been tasked with integrating Okta to validate credentials in a customers ActiveDirectory. They currently are Okta customers.

Ideally what I would like to do is program our windows .NET client to authenticate user credentials and then pass some information (securely) to our server application such that it can validate the session and then make further calls to the API to obtain user attributes.

We don't currently send passwords in the clear to our server. We use a hash and then just compare the incoming hash to the persisted hash. It seems the easy way to solve this problem is to just allow clear text passwords and then have the server authenticate the user and do all the work and just pass back our own token as part of our usual process.

Is there a way to get a SAML token on our client side to validate on the server side and get access to Okta? Would I have to generate a SAML assertion on the client side and pass the response up to the server?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a .NET application, are you able to enable it with WS-Federation?  If so, then you can then follow: https://support.okta.com/help/articles/Knowledge_Article/29510977-Configuring-the-Okta-Template-WS-Federation-Application

Reference: http://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/saml_guidance.html#reference